# How to tell Jackson to ignore a Boolean if it is null/false?

Tags: java, spring, serialization, jackson

I have class

```
@Data
public class MyClass {
  private Boolean flag;
}
```

And want to convert it to XML. However I need to ignore flag field during serialization if flag is not true.

So if **flag=true**, I want to get:

```
<MyClass><flag>true</flag></MyClass>
```

Otherwise(**if flag==null or flag==false**), I want to get:

```
<MyClass></MyClass>
```

How can I do it?

I tried @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL), but it works only for null values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic solution would be to use `JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM` like:

```
@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = TrueFilter.class)
private Boolean flag;
```

where TrueFilter would be like:

```
public static class TrueFilter {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object value) {
        return !Boolean.valueOf(true).equals(value);
    }
}
```

Also not so generic solution but if you need only to handle field `flag` you could try to override the getter with `NON_NULL` so like:

```
@Data
public class MyClass {
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private Boolean flag;

    public Boolean getFlag() {
        return (flag != null && flag) ? true : null;
    }
}
```