# Jackson ObjectMapper - How to exclude field when value is false after de-serialized from remote response?

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, objectmapper

I am making a remote call to external service A which would return the response as json and then using object mapper to de-serialize into `MyResponse` object. After that in my current service, I need to attach this object and output to the UI.

One of the field in `MyResponse` from service A is a boolean and I only want my UI response to include this field when the value is true. **Note that I don't have access to modify my `MyResponse` object** as it was read-only. So I created a **MixIn** class also tried couple of ways but it didn't work..

```
    public class MyResponse {

        private String stringValue;
        private int intValue;
        // Expectation: only include this field when value true, and exclude it when value is false
        private boolean booleanValue;
    }

    // @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "booleanValue" })
    // @JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)
    private static class MixInMyResponse {

    }

    // this would be my rest service eventually send myResponse to UI
    public MyResponse readFromRemote() throws IOException {
        String jsonAsString =
            "{\"stringValue\":\"a\",\"intValue\":1,\"booleanValue\":false}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // configure object mapper with mix in
        mapper.getDeserializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(MyResponse.class, MixInMyResponse.class);
        MyResponse myResponse = mapper.readValue(jsonAsString, MyResponse.class);
        // Expectation: writeValue needs only include booleanValue when value true, and exclude booleanValue when value is false
        String writeValue = mapper.writeValueAsString(myResponse);
        System.out.println(writeValue);
        return myResponse;
    }
```

1. Using `@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "booleanValue" })`: this would do the trick when value is false, but also it doesn't include the field when value is true
2. Using     `@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)`: when value is `false`, this would deserialized field `booleanValue` as false, so my returned `myResponse/writeValue` will still have this field to UI.

Is there any additional suggestion on that?

Comment: Have you looked this [Stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62538811/11719624)

Comment: @Chabo, Yes I have tried that way but get no luck, not sure if it's because I am using the MixIn cuz I cannot modify on original class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your own Serializer

```
public class MyResponseSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MyResponse> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(MyResponse myResponse, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("stringValue", myResponse.getStringValue());
        jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("intValue", myResponse.getIntValue());
        if (myResponse.isBooleanValue()) {
            jsonGenerator.writeBooleanField("booleanValue", myResponse.isBooleanValue());
        }
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Register it with the ObjectMapper

```
@Test
public void test3() throws IOException {
    MyResponse response1 = new MyResponse("response1", 1, true);
    MyResponse response2 = new MyResponse("response2", 1, false);

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(MyResponse.class, new MyResponseSerializer());
    objectMapper.registerModule(module);
    System.out.println(objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(response1));
    System.out.println(objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(response2));
}
```

See this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization)

I edited the original answer when I saw you couldn't modify MyResponse to add an annotation.

Comment: Hi this approach works when `writeValueAsString`, where I can debug inside the `customSerializer` see my `booleanValue` being ignored/contained in the write process. However, in my rest api, I still can see my final output contains the `booleanValue`, and I don't see my `customSerializer` breakpoint being hit..Does it mean the objectMapper I registered here was not used in my rest api final 
serialization?

Comment: I figured it out, I should actually the customized Deserialization instead of Serialization

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do something like this of course.

First of all, your `booleanValue` field should be boxed type `Boolean` not premitive type `boolean`. Because primitive type `boolean` default value is false.

You can crate a setter method for `booleanValue` and annotate it with `@JsonProperty("booleanValue")` like following.

```
public class MyResponse {
    private String stringValue;
    private int intValue;
    private Boolean booleanValue;

    @JsonProperty("booleanValue")
    public void anyNameYouWant(Boolean b) {
        if(b) this.booleanValue = true;
    }
    
    // getters and setters
}
```

Finally you can do the following,

```
String s = "{\"stringValue\":\"a\",\"intValue\":1,\"booleanValue\":false}";
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.readValue(s, MyResponse.class);
```

Comment: Thank you! That was good suggestion as well, unfortunately I cannot modify the `MyResponse` class content so I have to do it from the _outside_