# Jackson , defaulting empty or null value of boolean field to false

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jackson, json-deserialization, spring-restcontroller

I am using Kotlin Springboot stack and in a rest controller we have a **request body** model with field ***"isAgent"*** which is **boolean**.

The ask is to fail if the request is not having this boolean field.

We checked that, if we annotate @JsonProperty(required = true) over the field.
Jackson fails saying required parameter is not passed , which is inline with the ask.
But when fields is passed with "" OR " " OR Null value , jackson defaults it to false , but we want to fail this.

Any Idea how to achieve this in SpringBott without implementing custom Deserializer.

Comment: Custom deserializer sounds decent (its almost 1 liner, rest is autogenerated code). Possibly there is a flag that would do that or something.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62537257/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-boolean-if-it-is-null-false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom `ObjectMapper` bean setting `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES` to `true`

```kotlin
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary

@Configuration
class JacksonConfig

    @Bean
    @Primary
    fun objectMapper(): ObjectMapper {
        return ObjectMapper()
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES, true)
    }
}
```

Then a `Request` class like below would fail deserialization if `isUserAgent` is missing or null or blank

```kotlin
data class Request(
    @JsonProperty(value = "isUserAgent", required = true)
    val userAgentSpecified: Boolean,
)
```

Tests verifying the deserialization can be found on [github](https://github.com/devatherock/kotlin-demo/tree/jackson-boolean)

Comment: As he is using spring-boot, I’m pretty sure he doesn’t even need to define it in a custom object mapper class, but could simply set it in the application.yaml or properties: spring.jackson.deserialization.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES: true